# Vue.js + Laravel SPA - Socialite stateless Facebook Login

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, single-page-application, laravel-socialite

First to say that I already implement session based facebook login with laravel socialite and I registered proper facebook acc for developers and create app, but because of SPA I need to change to stateless solution...
The redirect throws **"Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)"** and check the following config, images and code...

My vue.js app works on **localhost:8080** and backend laravel app on **localhost:8000**

I installed barryvdh/laravel-cors an
d implement standard login with JWTToken

I already install laravel socialite

So, I setup config/services with proper credentials already

```
    'facebook' => [
    'client_id' => 'xxxxxxxx',
    'client_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxx',
    'redirect' => 'http://localhost:8000/login/facebook/callback',
]
```

I also register a good routes and I tested them 1000 times...

And when a GET send request it cannot be redirected on fb because of Response for preflight is invalid (redirect):

**SocialiteController**

```
public function redirectToFacebookProvider()
{
    return Socialite::driver('facebook')->stateless()->redirect(); // this throws error !!!
}
```

the error which I get in console is like on picture

[image]

1. It should open to me a popup to login on facebook ?
2. Why I have trouble with this redirect ?
   Any help ?

Comment: Hi, I've just been fighting a very similar issue and was able to solve it. What are you using client-side to make the request to your `redirectToFacebookProvider()` route? axios?

Comment: Axios...
Should I set callback to hit my frontend or backend application ?
Redirect route is on backend app, currently...

Comment: Socialite's `->redirect()` as the docs show you works great when you're hitting the routes through Blade views, but not for AJAXing.  What I had to do was instead return `Socialite::driver('whatever')->redirect()->getTargetUrl()` from my redirect route, and then set `window.location` to the returned URL in the axios callback.  Then it worked perfectly.

Comment: thank you man, I'll try that...

Comment: lainceline, Thanks man! You have saved my life. After your answer I have fixed my 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' CORS issue, this is really working solution. 10 days I have tryed to fix this. In the Socialite AbstractService class I have seen the redirect() method and in the return statement this method returns the ResponseRedirect and it will not work with Vue.

Comment: @Dulo so, did you manage to solve your issue? i'm facing a similar issue.

Comment: so what approach did you take then ?

Comment: @lainceline that works great but how do you handle the callback? It's still called to laravel right? So if there is an error how would you catch that in Vue JS?

Comment: Same issue here. Looks like there is no way to do social login with axios, because facebook will always made a force http redirect to the callbackUrl. I've tried everything and axios never catch the user information, facebook always me a hard http redirect.

I suggest using default facebook login.. or made a custom "socialite" module with Guzzlewith your own facebook backend.